# The "Save as PDF" option in the Developer Story section does not properly handle long links

Tags: bug, developer-story

When I export my developer story as a PDF, there are some links that exceed a single line in the PDF. When that happens, upon clicking on the link through the PDF, the link gets broken.

For example:

My developer story has a link to this URL:  https://www.youracclaim.com/badges/03992dbb-de4f-427a-aee7-ad775b1e0d1f/public_url

However, in the exported PDF, this URL splits into two lines. And the link only contains https://www.youracclaim.com/badges/03992dbb-de4f-427a-aee7-.

Comment: Workaround: if you remove `https://www.` and the final `/public_url` it still works and should fit.

Comment: That's a horrible workaround which only tackles a very specific subset of problematic URLs.

Comment: @tripleee If it worked for every case it would *not* be a workaround. Workarounds are by definition ugly hacks that work only thanks to the circumstances.

Comment: @tripleee thats also why its just a comment

Comment: Any updates on a real bug fix?